# Why static global variable is accessible in other file?

Tags: c, variables, scope, static, global-variables

```
//a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.c"
void main()
{
    int var;
    var = increment();
    var = increment();
    var = increment();
    count = count + 3;
    var = count;
    printf("%d", var);
}
```

```
//b.c
static int count;
int increment()
{
    ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Now as in b.c file I have a variable with name count and is static. Now this variable should not be accessible in a.c directly but in my case I can access and manipulate it. So am I missing something?

```
OUTPUT
6
```

Answer (score 5):

`#include "b.c"` in `a.c` makes `b.c` a part of the compilation of `a.c`; they are compiled as one source file.

To keep identifiers in separate source files separate, you compile them separately, without using `#include` to include one in the other. The separate compilations produce separate object files (`.o` files on Unix and Unix-like systems), which you then link together with a link command (which may be included in or performed by the `gcc` command).

Separating the source files also separates an identifier you do want to share between the two files, the function named `increment`. So `a.c` will not know about `increment`, and the compiler will complain. To deal with this for a single function, you can simply declare the function in `a.c` with `extern int increment();`. However, the usual technique for managing this sharing of identifiers is:

- Create a file named `b.h` that declares identifiers to be defined in `b.c` but shared with other source files.
- In `b.h`, declare `increment` with `extern int increment();`.
- In any source file that will use identifiers from `b.c`, include `b.h` with `#include "b.h"`.
- In `b.c`, also include `b.h`. This provides a check that the declarations in `b.h` match the definitions in `b.c`, because the compiler will see both while compiling `b.c` and report inconsistencies.

Answer (score 3):

You've included b.c in a.c, so they become a single unit as far as the compiler is concerned.  Because of this, you can see the static variable.

If you removed the include line, you wouldn't see either `count` or `increment`, although the latter would be implicitly declared because it is a function.